# Probability problem using choose

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

A termite enters a 3 ×3 ×3 stack of wooden cubes at one of its corners. The termite moves from one cube to the next by eating through the middle of the faces of the cube, rather than an edge or corner. After 6 delicious moves, the termite arrives at the cube in the opposite corner than it started from. If all possible paths were equally likely, what is the probability that the termite ate through the cube in the middle of the stack?

I approached this by first finding all the possible paths of the termite to go from one corner to its opposite. I found that this is just 12!/6!6!, because it can only go left and right since it eats through the cube's middle face only, so it can make three moves right or three moves left on the top or bottom. But I am not sure on what else to do from here and how I can calculate the probability.

Comment: PS: When they said "corner" they meant "corner cube".  Think of them as hollow boxes with connecting holes in the centers of their faces (filled with edable plugs).

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is for twelve moves through a two-dimensional grid.

This is six moves through a $3\times 3\times 3$ stack.

Let's say the termite starts in the bottom, left, backward corner-cube, then to reach the top, right, forward corner-cube, in six center face crossings, it must move in some arrangement of *twice topwise, twice right, and twice forward*.

Count the distinct arrangements of $\rm TTRRFF$ to obtain the **count for all six-move paths**.

---

What moves are required to do this passing through the central cube?

Break it into two stages: count the *arrangements* of moves which are required to reach the central cube, then count the *arrangements* of the remaining moves required to reach the final destination (ensuring only six moves are used in total).

Multiply these two counts to obtain the **count for favoured six-move paths**.

Divide and calculate to evaluate the probability. (Since we *are* assuming the *arrangements* of six-moves are all equally probable.)